# Can This Query be optimised in SQL, I want to remove Union

Tags: sql

```
 SELECT ORTABLE.SYSPERSUITV FROM ORD_NOARCHIVE ORTABLE WHERE 1 = 1
 AND (ORTABLE.STANDAARD = 'F') AND (ORTABLE.BEHCODE = 'BP') 
 AND (ORTABLE.SYSPERSUITV IS NOT NULL) AND (ORTABLE.ARCHIEF = 'F') 
 UNION 
 SELECT WATABLE.FK_RESOURCE_PERSON FROM PLN_WORKASSIGNMENT WATABLE WHERE 1 = 1 
 AND (WATABLE.BEHCODE = 'BP') AND (WATABLE.IS_ARCHIVED = 'F')
 AND NOT EXISTS ( 
 SELECT ORTABLE_2.SYSCODE FROM ORD_NOARCHIVE ORTABLE_2 WHERE 1 = 1
 AND (ORTABLE_2.SYSPERSUITV = WATABLE.FK_RESOURCE_PERSON)
 AND (ORTABLE_2.STANDAARD = 'F') AND (ORTABLE_2.BEHCODE = 'BP')
```

So this query combines two lists from two tables

Comment: Imagine for a second that we have no access to your tables, your data, or knowledge of the *logical intent* behind this query. Please improve your question by adding table definitions (`CREATE TABLE`), sample data (`INSERT`), the expected results, and *explain* the intent behind the query.

Comment: If we could improve your query with no knowledge of the above, it would be an entirely mechanical transformation that you should *expect the query optimizer to already be capable of*.

Comment: What is the actual problem - query is somewhat slow or what?

Comment: Just minimal, but `WHERE 1=1 AND CONDITION` is non-sense, just have  `WHERE CONDITION`…

Comment: @Aconcagua: This makes perfect sense when generating the query with a variable number of criteria. You just add `AND` for every condition. This doesn't slow things down.

Comment: The query looks fine to me. You have two very different queries to get values and you want the union of both. As it is possible for both queries to return the same value, you remove duplicates with `UNION` (rather than using `UNION ALL`). It doesn't look like you can optimise this by re-writing the query.

Comment: These seem to be totally independent tables – so I'd expect a union most likely being most efficient solution, though with appropriate indices you might get the subquery in second part faster. Apart from there might exist DMBS-specific options like postgre's materialised views that might bring some improvements under certain circumstances.